# Strange behavior with UIBezierPath addClip

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I'm trying to learn CoreGraphics and I have encountered a strange behavior.

I draw a rectangle and in it I draw given amount of diamonds,the shapes can be drawn with different filling (empty, filled and with stripes) my draw rect function looks like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIBezierPath* roundedRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds cornerRadius:9.0];

    //don't draw where the round corners "cut" the rectangle
    [roundedRect addClip];

    //set a white background
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill(self.bounds);

    //set a black frame
    [[UIColor darkGrayColor] setStroke];
    [roundedRect stroke];

    self.shade = STRIPED;
    self.color = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.number = 3;
    rectOffset = self.bounds.size.width / (self.number * 2);
    [self drawDiamondNumberOfTimes:self.number startOrigin:self.bounds.origin];
}
```

drawDiamondNumberOfTimes:startOrigin: is a recursive function that calculates the rectangle in which the shape will be drawing and draw the diamond boundaries using stroke

```
- (void) drawDiamondNumberOfTimes:(int) p_times startOrigin:(CGPoint) p_origin
{
    if( p_times > 0)
    {
        CGRect drawArea;
        drawArea.origin = CGPointMake(p_origin.x + rectOffset-shapeSize.width/2,    self.bounds.size.height/4);
        drawArea.size = shapeSize;

        UIBezierPath *diamond = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
        [diamond moveToPoint:CGPointMake(drawArea.origin.x, drawArea.origin.y+ shapeSize.height/2)];
        [diamond addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(drawArea.origin.x+shapeSize.width/2, drawArea.origin.y)];
        [diamond addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(drawArea.origin.x+shapeSize.width, drawArea.origin.y+ shapeSize.height/2)];
        [diamond addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(drawArea.origin.x+shapeSize.width/2, drawArea.origin.y+ shapeSize.height)];
        [diamond closePath];

        [self.color setStroke];
        [diamond stroke];
        [self drawShadeOfDraw:diamond atRect:drawArea];

        drawArea.origin.x += rectOffset + shapeSize.width/2;
        [self drawDiamondNumberOfTimes:p_times-1 startOrigin:drawArea.origin ];
    }
}
```

drawShadeOfDraw:atRect: set the different filling, where the strange behavior occurs.

With empty and solid fills it works perfect but with stripes, if I write [p_symbol addClip] then I get always one diamond striped even if self.number is set to 2 or 3. Without [p_symbol addClip] I get the correct number of diamonds but, of course, the stripes are all over the rectangle, here is the code for drawShadeOfDraw:atRect:

```
- (void)drawShadeOfDraw:(UIBezierPath*)p_symbol atRect:(CGRect)p_drawArea
{
    switch (self.shade)
    {
        case STRIPED:
        {
            [p_symbol addClip];
            for( int y = p_drawArea.origin.y; y < p_drawArea.origin.y+ p_drawArea.size.height; y+= 6)
            {  
                [p_symbol moveToPoint:CGPointMake(p_drawArea.origin.x, y)];
                [p_symbol addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(p_drawArea.origin.x+shapeSize.width, y)];
                [self.color setStroke];
                [p_symbol stroke];
            }
            break;
        }
        case SOLID:
        {
            [self.color setFill];
            [p_symbol fill];
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are some images:

[image: this is how it looks with addClip]

[image: and without addClip]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the clip is semi-permanent.  Once the clipping area has been "reduced", you can't grow it again, per se.  You can only restore it to a previous state.  To do that you call `CGContextSaveGState()` before setting up context state (including clipping), do some drawing with that state, and then call `CGContextRestoreGState()` afterward to restore the context state to what it was before.

So, I suggest that you bracket your two methods with calls to save and restore the context state. Use `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` to get a reference to the current context.